# Need command or script to download all repositories (in .ZIP) of particular organization from Github?

Tags: github

Looking for particular command or python script to download all repositories or sub branches of the particular organization from Github at once

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet? Where are you stuck in specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/3856584) (or [this one](https://gist.github.com/arangamani/5022951)) allows to list and clone all repos from an organization

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/twitter/repos?per_page=200 | ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; JSON.load(STDIN.read).each { |repo| %x[git clone #{repo["ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

You have the same in python with the project [`muhasturk/gitim`](https://github.com/muhasturk/gitim)

It isn't hard to [curl the zip archive of a repo instead](https://gist.github.com/loisaidasam/c0c07b95a84abe782cc0) (instead of cloning the repo):

```
curl -u '<git username>' -L -o master.zip https://github.com/<organization>/<reponame>/zipball/master
```